# .NET MAUI Blazor namespace can not be found in pages

Tags: blazor, maui

In >NET Maui Blazor .NET7 I have a Static class: AndroidServicemanger. The class is situated in [image: Plateforms/Andoid]

The namespacew for the class is :

```
namespace DriverApp_01.Platforms.Android
{
    public static class AndroidServiceManager
    {....
```

When i try to access the class from my index page located in
[image] the pages folder

```
   DriverApp_01.Platforms.Android.AndroidServiceManager.StartMyService();
```

I get the error

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Platforms' does not exist in the namespace 'DriverApp_01' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Static class directly. Such as:

```
#if ANDROID
     AndroidServiceManager.StartMyService();
#endif
```